# trying to run styleGAN in jyputer notebook, it says "tensorflow' has no attribute 'Dimension"

Tags: stylegan

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtAgo.png)!python encode_images.py --optimizer=lbfgs --face_mask=True --iterations=6 --use_lpips_loss=0 --use_discriminator_loss=0 --output_video=True aligned_images/ generated_images/ latent_representations/

print("\n************ Latent code optimization finished! ***************")

2021-08-24 13:33:11.033451: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "encode_images.py", line 12, in 
import dnnlib.tflib as tflib
File "C:\Users\bkvij\Office Rapid Innovation\StyleGAN Face Morphing - Arxiv Insights\stylegan-encoder\dnnlib\tflib_*init*_.py", line 8, in

from . import autosummary
File "C:\Users\bkvij\Office Rapid Innovation\StyleGAN Face Morphing - Arxiv Insights\stylegan-encoder\dnnlib\tflib\autosummary.py", line 31, in

from . import tfutil
File "C:\Users\bkvij\Office Rapid Innovation\StyleGAN Face Morphing - Arxiv Insights\stylegan-encoder\dnnlib\tflib\tfutil.py", line 34, in

def shape_to_list(shape: Iterable[tf.Dimension]) -> List[Union[int, None]]:
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Dimension'

Comment: what version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: I think you use TensorFlow v2  ,  use google colape and it will fix the problem for you ,otherwise, you will need to make virtual environment with TensorFlow v1 and run your code on it , The Answer below doesn't really solve the problem

Answer (score 7):

It's because tf.Dimension is deprecated.

Go to `stylegan/dnnlib/tflib/tfutil.py` and change the `tf.Dimension` in line 34 to `tf.compat.v1.Dimension`.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Faezeh's answer, you'll have to make the following edits to tfutils.py

From
`tf.Dimension` (line 34)
`tf.variable_scope` (line 74)
`tf.Session`   (line 128)

To
`tf.compat.v1.Dimension`
`tf.compat.v1.variable_scope`
`tf.compat.v1.Session`

alternatively, you could just download tensorflow 1.x and save yourself the hassle

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using TensorFlow v2,  use google colape and it will fix the problem for you, otherwise, you will need to make a virtual environment with **Python 3.6 TensorFlow 1.10 cuDNN 7.3.1**  and it will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

you can use it on terminal ' pip install tensorflow-addons==0.14.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).